How to plot absorbance from a Quantum ESPRESSO optical calculation using ε1, ε2, and energy data?
I have a calculation via DFT-RPA, which calculates epsilon_2 and energy (eV). For optical property calculation, we usually plot epsilon_2 vs energy (eV). However, I need to know to convert the y-axis parameter (epsilon_2) to absorbance. This is sometimes needed to compare with experimental data. Could you share any detail idea on this conversion? Any related paper suggestion would also be helpful.
We have $\epsilon_1$, $\epsilon_2$ and energy data. Now need to plot the absorbance vs energy.
We can plot like this (just in case can be helpful):


At which format do you have the real and imaginary parts of the dielectric function? Do you have the files epsr_prefix.dat and epsi_prefix.dat? If you could specify in which format you have your data in, I can write an answer. In any case, you get the absorption coefficient using the formula: $\alpha=\frac{2\omega \kappa(\omega)}{c}$. You have everything except $\kappa(\omega)$ which you can get by $\kappa(\omega) = \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{\varepsilon_1^2+\varepsilon_2^2}- \varepsilon_1}{2}}$. So you can plot this $\alpha$ against $\omega$ or $E=\hbar \omega$

Hi @AbdulMuhaymin-FreePalestine, thanks for your response. I have files in two different formats. In one format, it has omega or energy (eV), ϵ1 and ϵ2. The other format has the files epsr_prefix.dat and epsi_prefix.dat. It will be great to know in both ways, if possible.
And, regarding calculating κ(ω), could you please elaborate a bit about how to get that equation that you showed? Any paper link (where we can have that equation) would also be helpful.
And, what should be the units of the eligible parameters here?

I was also seeing this paper 'https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.103.186802', where they calculated the alpha parameter with a factor of 4 (instead of 2). The parameter description says to multiply dielectric susceptibility by distance to get the alpha. And it might be helpful to know how to calculate the dielectric susceptibility if we have energy (eV), ϵ1 and ϵ2 data. @AbdulMuhaymin-FreePalestine

What you have done so far is that you now have calculated the real and the imaginary parts of the dielectric functions, which is a function of $\omega$, i.e.,  $Re(\varepsilon(\omega)) = \varepsilon_1(\omega)$ and $Im(\varepsilon(\omega)) = \varepsilon_2(\omega)$. Now, the absorption coefficient $\alpha(\omega)$ is given by:
$$ 
\alpha(\omega) = \frac{2 \omega \kappa (\omega)}{c}, \tag{1}
$$
where $\kappa(\omega)$ is the imaginary part of the refractive index, which can also be calculated from the dielectric function using:$$ 
\kappa(\omega) = \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{(\varepsilon_1^2 + \varepsilon_2^2)} - \varepsilon_1}{2}}. \tag{2}
$$
You can find these derivations in Ch. 9 of the Principles Of Electronic Materials and Devices 4th Ed. by S.O. Kasap. There you will find, $\alpha$ in terms of $\lambda$ which is $\alpha(\lambda) = \frac{4\pi \kappa}{\lambda}$ which is the same thing as Equation (1). To get absorbance from absorption coefficient, you need to multiply it with your material thickness along that direction.
Now in this answer, you can see the format of such data files. Therefore, what you need to do is to extract the real and imaginary parts of the dielectric function as a function of energy in the three different axes. I am not sure about your material, but if it isotropic, then you should get the same value for all three axes ($\varepsilon_{xx} = \varepsilon_{yy} = \varepsilon_{zz} $). The following python code should work for that purpose (I haven't tested it since I don't have any example data file ready in hand and I don't have time to perform optical calculation to produce these data files). Note that here we only calculated for the absorbance along x-axis. You can modify the code to extract data from the 3rd column instead of the second column to get $\alpha_y$ and same goes for $\alpha_z$
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

c = 3e8  # m/s
hbar = 6.6e-16  # eV.s

energy, real_epsilon_x, _, _ = np.loadtxt('epsr_prefix.dat', unpack=True)
energy, imag_epsilon_x, _, _ = np.loadtxt('epsi_prefix.dat', unpack=True)

alpha_x = (2*energy)/(c*hbar) * np.sqrt((np.sqrt((real_epsilon_x)**2 + (imag_epsilon_x)**2) - real_epsilon_x) / 2)

# uncomment the following line if you know the thickness of your material
# along the x-direction and then change the x-label accordingly too:
# absorbance = alpha_x * thickness

plt.plot(energy, alpha_x)
plt.set_xlabel('Energy (eV)')
plt.set_ylabel('Absorption coefficient (1/m)')
plt.show()


Thank you very much @Abdul Muhaymin -Free palestine. This makes sense if I want to calculate the axial contributions, right (like alpha_x, alpha_y, alpha_z)?
So, my first query is, In general, for any arbitrary system, how to get the epsilon_1 and epsilon_2 (instead of epsilon_1_x and epsilon_2_x), and thereby alpha (instead of alpha_x)?
The second query is, for some reason, I did not find the derivation of κ(ω) in Ch. 9 of the Principles Of Electronic Materials and Devices 4th Ed. by S.O. Kasap. Could you show it here (or any screenshot would also be fine)?

@Sak Strictly speaking, dielectric functions are 2nd rank tensors in general. So maybe for lower dimensional material, or for isotropic material, you have $\alpha_{xx}=\alpha_{yy}$ or $\alpha_{xx}=\alpha_{yy}=\alpha_{zz}$, in general you do not have this and you have to specify along which direction you are plotting your absorbance. From Kasap's book, you can derive those for example from Example 9.12, equation 9.57, etc. If you are looking for equation (2), this is equation (5.30) of this book. I think section 5.9 and 3.4 of that book are related.

Thanks @Abdul Muhaymin -Free Palestine. Does the units of 'hbar' needs to be in SI unit as well? I mean, does the 'eV' needs to be converted here? This is becasue the equation in the code contains both 'c' and 'hbar', where 'c' is in SI unit and hbar has units with 'eV'.

@Sak no need for that. In eps*_prefix.dat, the values of energy are in $\mathrm{eV}$ unit. So, keep the hbar in $\mathrm{eV},.\mathrm{s}$ so that the $\mathrm{eV}$ would cancel and $\mathrm{s}$ remains in the denominator. There is also $c$ in the denominator which has unit of $\mathrm{m/s}$. So at the end, only $\mathrm{m}$ remains in the denominator or in other words, the absorption coefficient has the unit of $\mathrm{1/m}$. I added the unit as axis labels in the code. So, absorption coefficient has a unit of length which when multiplied by thickness would give unitless absorbance.
